# bug in django-select2 design with bootstrap - select field to narrow

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms, jquery-select2

I have a django 1.6.2 project (python 3.3), with bootstrap 3 theme. I have installed the wanted https://github.com/t0m/select2-bootstrap-css, and it is working properly.

But 'select' field is too narrow (tight).

[image: Subproduct field is to narrow]

This is a known bug (https://github.com/t0m/select2-bootstrap-css/issues/42)

Does anybody know the solution?

Does anybody know another django widget for ajax selection form field?

Answer (score 0):

I think, I've found a trivial solution:

https://github.com/t0m/select2-bootstrap-css/issues/42#issuecomment-68210742